# Writing a text file error using python 3.x "with open" function

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement

I am writing a text file with some of the data I analyzed using python. I am running into some error messages. Below is my code.

```
sixteen=0.1
fifteen=0.3
fourteen=-.4
fourteen_revised=1
thirteen=2

with open('TMV_AVD.txt','w') as f:
    f. write('16+',sixteen+'\n','15+', fifteen+'\n','14+',\
             fourteen+'\n','14-',fourteen_revised+'\n', '13-', thirteen)
```

What I want in my text file is the following

```
16+,0.1
15+,0.3
14+,-.4
14-,1
13-,2
```

The error message I get is the following.

```
ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32') dtype('<U32').
```

I thought I understood `with open` function. Your suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Any suggestions?

Comment: I get `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'`.

Comment: use "your_string".format()

Comment: Please post the full text of the error you're getting in the body of  your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `open()` and its context manager, it has to do with the concatenation of your data and mismatched types. Your example, tho, should throw a different error - I imagine the error you posted stems from some Pandas structure.

You can let [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) attempt to concatenate your data as:

```
with open('TMV_AVD.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('16+,{}\n15+,{}\n14+,{}\n14-,{}\n13-,{}'.format(sixteen, fifteen, fourteen,
                                                            fourteen_revised, thirteen))
```

Or, if using Python 3.6+ you can directly build an *f string*:

```
f.write(f"16+,{sixteen}\n15+,{fifteen}\n14+,{fourteen}\n14-,{fourteen_revised}\n13-,{thirteen}")
```

Or you'll have to manually turn your data into a proper format before concatenating.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is overly complicated. I strongly recommend you use a list of tuples or `OrderedDict` to store your variables. Then use a simple `for` loop:

```
d = [('sixteen', ('16+', '0.1')),
     ('fifteen', ('15+', '0.3')),
     ('fourteen', ('14+', '-.4')),
     ('fourteen_revised', ('14-', '1')),
     ('thirteen', ('13-', '2'))]

with open('TMV_AVD.txt', 'w') as f:
    for _, vals in d:
        f.write(','.join(vals)+'\n')
```